# Can't cancel default action on ajax form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, internet-explorer

I have a form and a piece of `javascript` code to create `AJAX` forms. The weird thing is when i submit my form in Internet Explorer the only thing that displays is `[object Object]`. The form works fine in Google Chrome. Here is my code:

Form header:

```
<form id="page-details-form" class="ajax-form" name="page-details-form" method="POST" action="/pages/save/1">
```

Javascript listener:

```
<script>
    $(function(){

        $(document).on("submit",".ajax-form",function(e){
            if (window.event) {
                window.event.returnValue = false;
            }           
            e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

            $('.form-message').remove();

            if($('#onSubmitJsEval').html() && $('#onSubmitJsEval').html().length > 0)
            {
                eval($('#onSubmitJsEval').html());
            }

            var submitBtnValue  = $('#submitBtn').html();
            var formId          = $(this).attr('id');
            var postData        = $(this).serializeArray();

            $('#submitBtn')     .html('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $('p.has-error')    .remove();
            $('div.has-error')  .removeClass('has-error');

            $.post($(this).attr('action'), postData, function(jsonResponse)
            {
                var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(jsonResponse);

                if(jsonObject.success == true)
                {
                    $('<div class="<?=MESSAGE_SUCCESS_CLASS?>"><?=MESSAGE_SUCCESS_PREFIX?>'+jsonObject.message+'</div>' ).insertBefore( "#" + formId + " h2" );
                    if(jsonObject.insertedId > 0)
                    {
                        var stringPath = window.location.pathname.substr(window.location.pathname.length - 1);

                        document.location.href = window.location.pathname + ((stringPath != "/") ? "/" : "") + jsonObject.insertedId;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    $('<div class="<?=MESSAGE_ERROR_CLASS?>"><?=MESSAGE_ERROR_PREFIX?>'+jsonObject.message+'</div>' ).insertBefore( "#" + formId + " h2" );
                    $.each(jsonObject.errors, function(index, value){

                        $('[name='+index+']').parent().addClass('has-error');
                        $('[name='+index+']').after('<p class="has-error help-block">'+value+'</p>');
                    })

                }

                $('#submitBtn').html(submitBtnValue);
            });

        });


    }); 

</script>
```

I tried several options besides the current option:

- `if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();`
- `e.returnValue = false`
- `e.returnValue = false` after `e.preventDefault`

Does anyone have a idea? If i need to publish more code please let me know. I can post all the code if you want.

Many thanks!

Comment: `e.returnValue = false;;` double semicolons?? and why not you just try with `e.preventDefault();`? why do you need a if condition for this?

Comment: I'm sorry i just pasted the code wrong. I update it know with the full javascript code.

Comment: Did you try a simple `return false;`?

Comment: It looks like `e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;` does work for prevent the default because it doesn't redirect to SITE/save/details/1 but instead of that it displays `[object Object]`

Answer (score 1):

You will need a combination of e.preventDefault() and return false, with handling code inbetween.

```
$(document).on("submit", ".ajax-form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Do your stuff here
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It stil doens't work. I added `return false` add the end and `e.preventDefault();` as the first rule. But the output is different now. Internet explorer prints now the JSON response instead of `[object Object]`. So it gues it just submits the form because it goes to SITE/pages/save/1.

Comment: It looks like `e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;` does work for prevent the default because it doesn't redirect to SITE/save/details/1 but instead of that it displays `[object Object]`. So when i submit the form Internet Explorer displays `[object Object]` but i just have to do the AJAX call and the action after the AJAX call. The specific question is why does Internet Explorer show this message instead of doing nothing with the current window?

Comment: Why not use the standard jQuery function getJSON (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson) to load JSON-encoded data? Or have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
My point is that jQuery provides good compatibility among most browsers.

Comment: Example of the above, standard ajax call to load JSON data:

    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'get.php',
    data: {
        //variables
        },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        //handling
    },
    error: function() {
        //error handling
    }
});